# Como corrigir um script em JQuery que usa um WebService para fazer upload de um arquivo

Tags: jquery, servidor, pdf

Eu estou tentando salvar um arquivo PDF na minha pasta do servidor usando um WebService. Eu acho que isso deveria ser uma tarefa simples, mas depois de pesquisar muito na WEB eu descobri o script abaixo mas quando eu rodo ele estou recebendo o erro "InternalError: too much recursion". Este erro ocorre no jquery.min.js

```
function salva2(quality = .10) {
        const filename = 'ThisIsYourPDFFilename.pdf';

        html2canvas(document.querySelector('#renderPDF'),
            { scale: quality }
        ).then(canvas => {
            let pdf = new jsPDF('p', 'mm', 'a4');
            window.onePageCanvas = document.createElement("canvas");
            window.onePageCanvas = canvas.toDataUR;
            pdf.addImage(canvas.toDataURL('image/png'), 'PNG', 0, 0, 211, 298);
            //pdf.save(filename);


            jQuery.ajax({
                url: '/WebserviceFace/UploadFile',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/pdf; charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'pdf',
                data: {
                    fileName: 'Teste1',
                    contentType: 'pdf',
                    bytes: pdf,
                },
                error: function (request, status, error) {
                },
                sucess: function (data, status, request) {
                }
            })
        });
    }
```

Alguém pode me apontar o que estou fazendo errado .. Por favor

Agradeço antecipadamente